# insert the space into Filereader

Tags: c#, filereader, flat-file

I have to write the code to insert the space in middle of falt file.
I have text as below, each line column length should be same

```
123
123256
123323
```

the above string should looks like

```
123---   
234256
987323
```

After 123 we need space. could you suggest how to do this.

I have loaded the file into string dr = file.ReadToEnd();

Comment: And readline from original, writing to a temporary file, and then doing a rename afterward would be a good thing as well, especially if the files are big.

Answer (score 0):

Use the string `split` function to split your lines at the line break (either `\n` or `System.Environment.NewLine`, depending your desires).  Iterate over the returned array to `Trim()` each string, then use the `PadRight` function to produce a new string of the desired length with the desired trailing characters.  Then use one of the many `IO` write functions to output to a new file or overwrite the existing file.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
using(FileStream input = new FileStream(inputFileName,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read))
{
  TextReader reader = new StreamReader(input);
  using (FileStream output = new FileStream(OutputFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
  {
    TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(output);
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
     {
       writer.WriteLine(line.PadRight(6,' '));
     } 
  }
}
```

Off the top of my head this, so may be a silly in it.

Then rename outputFileName to inputFileName